Prove that given set does not have Lipschitz boundary.
Definition 28.6.
We say that $G$ is a domain with the Lipschitz boundary if it is bounded (it may be multiply connected, in general) and if there exist positive constants $\alpha$, $\beta$, a finite number $m$ of Cartesian coordinate systems $x_1^{(r)}, \ldots, x_N^{(r)}, r = 1, \ldots, m,$ and $m$ functions $a_r(x_1^{(r)}, \ldots, x_{N-1}^{(r)})$ which are continuous in the $(N - 1)$-dimensional cubes $K^{(r)}$,
$$
|x_i^{(r)}| < \alpha, \quad i = 1, \ldots, N - 1,
$$
so that
(a) every point $x$ of the boundary $\Gamma$ can be expressed in at least one of the considered coordinate systems in the form
$$
x = [(x_1^{(r)}, \ldots, x_{N-1}^{(r)}), a_r(x_1^{(r)}, \ldots, x_{N-1}^{(r)})];
$$
(b)the points $x = (x_1^{(r)}, \ldots, x_{N-1}^{(r)}, x_N^{(r)})$ for which we have
$$
|x_i^{(r)}| < \alpha, \quad i = 1, \ldots, N - 1,
$$
and
$$
a_r(x_1^{(r)}, \ldots, x_{N-1}^{(r)}) < x_N^{(r)} < a_r(x_1^{(r)}, \ldots, x_{N-1}^{(r)}) + \beta, 
$$
or
$$
a_r(x_1^{(r)}, \ldots, x_{N-1}^{(r)}) - \beta < x_N^{(r)} < a_r(x_1^{(r)}, \ldots, x_{N-1}^{(r)}), 
$$
lie in $G$, or outside of $\bar{G}$, respectively;
(c) each of the functions $a_r(x_1^{(r)}, \ldots, x_{N-1}^{(r)}), \, r = 1, \ldots, m,$ satisfies the Lipschitz condition on the cube $K^{(r)}$, i.e., there exists a constant $L$ such that for any two points $(y_1^{(r)}, \ldots, y_{N-1}^{(r)})$ and $(x_1^{(r)}, \ldots, x_{N-1}^{(r)})$ from this cube we have
$$
|a_r(y_1^{(r)}, \ldots, y_{N-1}^{(r)}) - a_r(x_1^{(r)}, \ldots, x_{N-1}^{(r)})| \leq L\sqrt{(y_1^{(r)} - x_1^{(r)})^2 + \ldots + (y_{N-1}^{(r)} - x_{N-1}^{(r)})^2}. 
$$
Question: Prove that given set does not have Lipschitz boundary.

My attempt
To prove this I need to find the portion of the boundary in which (a),(b) and (c) must be wrong. I am unable to find such portion.
Could you help me?
Is punctured disc a Lipschitz domain?
I see this answer.  May I know which theorem consider the boundary of the set as the level set of Lipschitz function help me to prove that the boundary is a Lipschitz boundary?
